# Initialise `std::array` with parameter pack arguments

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae, template-argument-deduction

There's structure `HasArray` with template parameters typename `T` and size_t `N`.

```cpp
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct HasArray {
  // enable_if sizeof...(T) equals N
  template<typename ... Types, typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Types) == N, int>::type = 0>
  explicit HasArray(Types ... s) : arr { s... } {}
 protected:
  std::array<T, N> arr;
};
```

I would like to initialize the member array `arr` with the parameter-pack arguments of the constructor.

```cpp
HasArray<uint32_t, 2> foo(7, 13);
```

But that yields a `c++11-narrowing` warning in Clang.

```
error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'std::__1::array<unsigned int, 2>::value_type' (aka 'unsigned int') in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
```

I see no way to cast all `s`'s of type `Types` to type `T`. Is there one?

**Edit** thanks for all answers. I ended up using `static_cast<>` on the packed parameters and SFINAE when not convertible:

```cpp
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct HasArray {
  // Use `static_cast` to construct `arr` with `s`
  // Add `enable_if` all `Types` are `is_convertible`
  template<typename ... Types, 
    typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Types) == N, int>::type = 0,
    typename std::enable_if<(std::is_convertible<Types, T>::value && ...), int>::type = 0>
  explicit HasArray(Types ... s) : arr { static_cast<T>(s)... } {}
 protected:
  std::array<T, N> arr;
};
```

Comment: I suppose is `sizeof...(Types) == N`; anyway: C++11, C++14 or C++17?

Comment: Do you want to initialize `arr` with any value convertible to `T` type or just values of type `T`?

Comment: [at]max66, yes that's a typo in the excerpt, sorry.
@DanM. I would like to construct `HasArray` with any value convertible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to construct `std::array` from any value convertible to `T`, then the easiest solution would be just to add `static_cast<T>(...)` in your constructor.

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct HasArray {
  template<typename ... Types,
           typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Types) == N, int>::type = 0>
  explicit HasArray(Types ... s) : arr {static_cast<T>(s)... } {}
protected:
  std::array<T, N> arr;
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/TEoZOG

It's also possible to "SFINAE out" the constructor in case such conversion is not possible, but In my opinion the default error message would be better in current simple case and you could add static_asserts with better message in constructor body.

Answer (score 3):

You might use intermediate class:

```
template <std::size_t, typename T>
using always_t = T;

template <typename T, typename Seq>
struct HasArrayImpl;

template <typename T, std::size_t...Is>
struct HasArrayImpl<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    explicit HasArrayImpl(always_t<Is, T> ... v) : arr { v... } {}
protected:
    std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> arr;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
using HasArray = HasArrayImpl<T, std::make_index_sequence<N>>;
```

Else, you can extend your SFINAE to convertible type and **explicitly** convert values

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct HasArray {
    // enable_if sizeof...(T) equals N
    template <typename ... Types,
             std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Types) == N)
                                   && (std::is_convertible<Types, T>::value && ...),
                              int>::type = 0>
    explicit HasArray(Types ... s) : arr{ static_cast<T>(s)... } {}
 protected:
    std::array<T, N> arr;
};
```

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure if I like the actual type having the full index sequence as template parameters. It's valid C++ of course, but you will make a mess of a lot of tools, error messages, binary size (think about the mangled name of `void foo(HasArray<int, 100>& x)`)... This answer is technically correct but imo not advisable in practice.

Comment: Also note that `std::is_convertible` is more strict than `static_cast`. The former only considers [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible), whereas the latter can do [a good deal more](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast).

Answer (score 1):

> I see no way to enforce that all types Types must be of type T. Is there one?

I don't understand, from your question if you want that `Types` are deducible template types, and all of they are deduced **exactly** as `T`, or if you want a no-template constructor that receive exaclty `N` values of type `T`.

The first case is simple (if you can use C++17 template folding; a little more complicated otherwise) because you can use `std::is_same`

```
template <typename ... Types,
          typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(Types) == N) 
              && (... && std::is_same<Types, T>::value), int>::type = 0>
explicit HasArray(Types ... s) : arr {{ s... }}
 { }
```

For second case I propose a variation of the Jarod42 solution that uses a specialization of `HasArray` instead of a intermediate class (edit: added an improvement from Jarod42 itself; thanks!):

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N, typename = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct HasArray;

template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct HasArray<T, N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 {
   static_assert( sizeof...(Is) == N , "wrong sequence size" );

   protected:
      std::array<T, N> arr;

   public:
      explicit HasArray(getType<T, Is> ... s) : arr {{ s... }}
       { }
 };
```

where `getType` is

```
template <typename T, std::size_t>
using getType = T;
```

In first case,

```
HasArray<std::uint32_t, 2> foo(7, 13);
```

gives compilation error because `7` and `13` are deduced as `int` that isn't `std::uin32_t`.

In second case it compile becase `HasArray` has a constructor

```
HasArray(std::uint32_t, std::uint32_t)
```

and the `int`s are converted to `std::uint32_t`.

The following is a full compiling C++14 example for the second case

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, std::size_t>
using getType = T;

template<typename T, std::size_t N, typename = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct HasArray;

template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct HasArray<T, N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 {
   static_assert( sizeof...(Is) == N , "wrong sequence size" );

   protected:
      std::array<T, N> arr;

   public:
      explicit HasArray(getType<T, Is> ... s) : arr {{ s... }}
       { }
 };

int main ()
 {
   HasArray<std::uint32_t, 2> foo(7, 13);
 }
```

Comment: You probably want a `static_assert(N == sizeof...(Is))`, else `HasArray<int, 42, std::index_sequence<>>` would be valid type :-/

Comment: @Jarod42 - I seemed to forget something: `HasArray` can be hijacked. Thanks.